# Factory class so I can change my rest client down the road

Tags: java, design-patterns

As of now I have a rest client called RestClient it implements an interface called IRestClient. Throughout my code I use IRestClient when declaring the rest clients. But several places I create the client using the new operator. So if I at some point want to change the client to NewRestClient I would have to go through my code and find all the places where I created the client.

What would be a good way to address this issue? Would a factory class like the one below be ok.

```
class RestClientFactory
{
    public static IRestClient create()
    {
        return new RestClient();
    }
}
```

Atleast that way I would only have one place to change RestClient() to NewRestClient().

Comment: [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) might be a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factory method pattern will only be necessary if you want/need to provide an exact implementation of `IRestClient` based on some arguments. Since this doesn't seem to be your case, you will be good by [programming oriented to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197). So, instead of having this:

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
restClient.foo("bar");
```

You will have this:

```
//declare the variable as interface
//assign the value with the class implementation
IRestClient restClient = new RestClient();
restClient.foo("bar");
```

So if you need a new implementation, just change the current implementationto the desired one:

```
IRestClient restClient = new FooRestClient();
//rest of the code remains intact
restClient.foo("bar");
```

If you want to move this into [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), then you will have something like this:

```
class RestClientFactory {
    public static IRestClient defaultRestClient() {
        return new RestClient();
    }
    public static IRestClient createRestClient(String name) {
        String realName = name.toLowerCase();
        switch(realName) {
            case "foo":
                return new FooRestClient();
            case "bar":
                return new BarRestClient();
            //and on...
            default:
                return defaultRestClient();
        }
    }
}
```

And then you will have to initialize the instance by calling the respective method from the factory:

```
IRestClient restClient = RestClientFactory.createRestClient("foo");
//rest of the code remains intact
restClient.foo("bar");
```

Comment: They already have this though. I believe Q is about creation of the `RestClient` so can be swapped out by editing in one place.

Comment: @weston then, as explained in my answer, there is no problem. You're just editing at a single place. If there are lot of places to change, well... that's another problem that not even the factory method can fulfill.